# Openshift online 3 Application down on free tier

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am using **OpenShift online 3**

[image]

Deployed a simple node JS application which is launching some times on default router with similar to below URL:

http://***-***.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/

My issue is 99% of time the app is going down even for 1 user,
and most of the times the app is showing this screen not sure what to fix as this is working very few times.

[image]

How can I fix this in free OpenShift online 3 free tier?

Earlier I am using OpenShift 2 free, and never faced such an issue.

Comment: The status page for us-east-1 is not showing any known issues. Run ``oc get pods --watch`` and see if pods are terminating and restarting, indicating that your application container keeps crashing and restarting. This would cause it to not show as available as it restarts. If evidence of it crashing, use ``oc logs`` on the pods to see what is being logged. You can also run ``oc get events --watch`` to look at any events being generated.